# MaxScript - Simple Script, Attachment Controler

Tags: maxscript

I am begginer with Maxscript. I am trying to make a simple script in Max Script, for animated scene. Tried using macro recorder but it doesn't record that action that I need.
So, I have a number of points in a scene that all have Attachment Constraint Controller,
I need to uncheck  checkbox 'Align to Surface' using script.

After I tried with macro recorder I explore scripts on Scriptspot and documentation but couldn't find and example that I can learn from

```
checkbox chk_align "Align To Surface" checked:false
```

returns error

I appreciate help with this problem.

SCREENSHOT:

[Attachment Controler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tk5Mj.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want that for a single selected object:

```
(getClassInstances Attachment target:$).align = off
```

For all controller instances in the scene:

```
(getClassInstances Attachment).align = off
```